# How create a increment code to a value like "al003651" in PHP?

Tags: php, string, iteration

Hi i need create a increment code to values like:

**al003651 -> al003652 -> al003653**

or

**m000390  -> m000391  -> m000392**

note that the number of zeros can vary...

Thanks,
Celso.

Comment: That sounds trivial enough to do with simple string manipulations. Where are you getting stuck so far?

Comment: An application that requires this kind of manipulation is probably a badly designed one. What is this for? Why not just use numeric codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has these wonderful incrementors

```
$str = 'al003651';

for ($i = 0; $i < 16; $i++)
    echo $str++,'<br />';

echo '<hr />';

$str = 'm000390';

for ($i = 0; $i < 16; $i++)
    echo $str++,'<br />';
```

Though you'll need to trap for a change of prefix

```
$str = 'z91';

for ($i = 0; $i < 16; $i++)
    echo $str++,'<br />';
```

When the numeric part has incremented to all 9's, the alpha prefix will change

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$code = 'al003651';
preg_match("~([a-z]+)(\d+)~", $code, $results);
$length = strlen($results[2]);

//add one to the number
$number = (int) $results[2];
$number += 1;

//concat again
$code = $results[1];

//attach zeros
$diff = abs($length - strlen('' . $number));
$code .= str_repeat('0', $diff);

//attach new code
$code .= $number;
echo $code;
?>
```

Comment: +1, however, I recommend using `str_repeat` instead of that ugly `for` loop ;)